# Only display views that are acceptable targets and remove "Cannot find view in scope." error

Tags: swiftui

I would like to navigate to a different view depending on target (iOS, macOS, watchOS, etc.). How would I achieve this in SwiftUI?

I also need to avoid "Cannot find 'WatchView' in scope" error as WatchView does not share the same Target Membership as iOSView.

Example:

```
var body: some View {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        iOSView()
    } else if #available(watchOS 2, *) {
        WatchView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are run-time checkers not compiler, so compiler see everything in each branch, so everything should be present, otherwise you just need something else.

Comment: You may be looking for `#if os(iOS)` style checks

Answer (score 1):

As Asperi and jnpdx stated, it needed to be `#if`:

```
var body: some View {
#if os(watchOS)
    WatchView()
#else
    iOSView()
#endif
}
```